# Como puedo usar una variable de abajo hacia arriba? Python

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, scraping, peticiones

Buen día. Tengo un gran problema con mi código, De la estructura de código, Tengo una variable declarada dentro de un if al final de la estructura y necesito poner esa variable en otro if que esta al principio de la estructura.
Es posible?.

El codigo lo que hace es esto:

1- Extrae una palabra de las celdas especificas en Excel. Con esa palabra hago una peticion a las paginas especificas.  El if lo que hace es cambiar a la siguiente celda despues de 4 clicks en el boton.

2- teniendo ya la pagina con la petición ya hecha, Lo uso para hacer web-scraping y extraigo un numero en cadena que lo guardo en la variable "ncaps", Como ven justo abajo lo utilizo convirtiéndolo con int().

3- Esa variable "ncaps" es la necesito es usar pero al principio del codigo. Es posible? Espero que si :(

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import contextlib
import io
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pyautogui
import time
from threading import Thread
import re
ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x500")
path = 'C:\\Users\\acalobish\\Desktop\\Codigos\\Proyecto\\filtro.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename = path)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja1')
sheet_ranges = wb.active



num1= 1
num2 = 0
num3 = 0
num4 = 0
i = 1
clic = 4
zx = 1
num5 = 0
def sec():
    global i, clic,zx,num1,num2,num3,num4,num5
    clic += 1
    if clic >= 4: #el 4 es lo que necesio reeempazar por ncaps
        clic = 0
        if i > 10:
            i = 1
        num1 = sheet_ranges['A'+str(i)].value # busqueda por link tio anime
        num2 = sheet_ranges['B'+str(i)].value # busqueda por nombre
        num3 = sheet_ranges['C'+str(i)].value # busqueda por link monoschinos
        i+=1
    a=  [num1]
    a1= [num2]
    a2= [num3]
    

    celdas = [a]
    celdas1 = [a1]
    celdas2 = [a2]

    for cell in celdas:
        ap = cell
    for cell1 in celdas1:
        ap1 = cell1
    for cell2 in celdas2:
        ap2 = cell2



    urlr = "https://www.rzanime.com/search"

    url = "https://tioanime.com/directorio"

    url1 = "https://monoschinos.com/search"
    payloadr = {'q':ap1} #peticion rzanime
    payload = {'q':ap1} #peticiones tioanime
    payload1 = {'q':ap1} #peticiones monoschinos
    rz = requests.get(urlr, params=payloadr)
    r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
    r1 = requests.get(url1,params=payload1)
    soupr = BeautifulSoup(rz.content, 'html.parser')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.content, 'html.parser')

    datr = soupr.find_all('div', class_="card-thumbnail")[0].find('a')
    if(datr.get('href').rsplit('/',1)[1].rsplit('.html')[0] in str(ap2).rsplit('-sub-español')[0]):
        rz = (datr.get('href'))
    else:
        rz = ("no se encontro")

    dat1 = soup.find_all('a', href=True)[6]
    if (dat1.get('href').rsplit('/',1)[1] in ap):
        ta = ("https://tioanime.com/anime/"+dat1.get('href').rsplit('/',1)[1])
    else:
        ta = ("no se encontro")

    mda = soup1.find_all('a', class_="link-anime")[0]
    if (mda.get('href').rsplit('/',1)[1] in ap2):
        mon = (mda.get('href'))
    else:
        mon=("no se encontro")
        
    url3 = ta
    payload3 = {'q':ap1}
    r2 = requests.get(url3)
    soup3 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content, 'html.parser')
    for tcap in soup3.find_all('script')[20]:
        ncaps = tcap.split('[')[2].split(',')[0] # variable ncaps que necesito poner arriba
    for ttcaps in soup3.find_all('meta', property="og:url"):
        nm = ttcaps.get('content').rsplit('/',1)[1]
    mon1 = mon.rsplit("/",1)[1]
    if zx > int(ncaps):
        zx = 1
    nam = "https://tioanime.com/ver/"+nm+'-'+str(zx)
    nam1 = "https://monoschinos.com/ver/"+mon1.rsplit('-',2)[0]+'-episodio-'+str(zx)
    username_label = Label(text=nam, bg="#FFEEDD")
    username_label.place(x=22, y=70)
    username1_label = Label(text=nam1, bg="#FFEEDD")
    username1_label.place(x=22,y=100)
    rz_label = Label(text=rz,bg="#FFEEDD")
    rz_label.place(x=22,y=130)
    zx+=1
boton = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Compila pls", command=sec, width="30", height="2", bg="#00CD63")
boton.place(x=22, y=320)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta.

Comment: @gcoronel99 Gracias por responder!, Tratare de explicarlo mejor. de la estructura de codigo. tengo una variable declarada en medio de la estructura. Esa variable esta declarada dentro de un `if` y necesito poner esa variable al en otro if que esta al principio de la estructura. Suena loco pero es muy necesario :/

Comment: Todavía no me queda muy claro, te recomendaría que pusieras el `for` donde defines `ncaps` arriba de el `if`, Hay que entender que Python es interpretado, el orden de la lineas es importante.

Comment: @gcoronel99 claro eso seria lo ideal, Lo que sucede es que con la primera parte del código Extraigo una palabra de una celda de excel y con esa palabra hago una Petición a una pagina, Luego con la segunda parte del codigo hago el web-scraping a la pagina que tiene la petición ya hecha. y de ahi sale el `ncaps` que viene a ser un numero. Ese numero lo necesito para reemplazar el numero 4 de la primera parte. Es por eso que no puedo moverlos :/

Comment: Busca un tutorial, @RicharlyxD, de cómo funcionan las funciones en programación. Es lo que necesitas. Ejemplo: https://entrenamiento-python-basico.readthedocs.io/es/latest/leccion5/funciones.html

Comment: Pienso que no conoces los términos, argumentos y funciones. Las funciones te permiten usar tus variable como argumento y retornarlo. Una función puede invocar a otras. Lo que quiere decir es que lo mejor es que separes tu código por funciones y ncaps la mandes como parámetro de una función. Mira el tutorial que te recomendó @Saelyth, también te lo recomiendo ;).

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que no se entiene buen bien tu pregunta, asi que puede que está no sea la respuesta.

Cuando nos encontramos con que queremos usar un dato que aun no tenemos, lo usual es declararlo con algùn valor *imposible*, de tal manera que lleve la ejecución por un camino seguro.

Entiendo que quieres evitar entrar en el `if` antes de tiempo:

```
clic += 1
if clic >= 4: #el 4 es lo que tengo que reemplazar
    clic = 0
```

En ese caso, declara `ncap` con un valor fuera de rango. Por ejemplo, si `ncap` sólo asume valores positivos, usa

```
ncap = -1
clic += 1
if clic >= ncap: 
    clic = 0
```

Ahora, si este còdigo está dentro de un ciclo, inicializa `ncap` fuera del ciclo, para asegurar que la inicialización a -1 se haga sólo una vez:

```
ncap = -1
while alguna_condicion:
    clic += 1
    if clic >= ncap: 
        clic = 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder!, Bueno el problema que tengo al parecer no es posible resolver. Sucede que tengo un `if` que me da un variable(un numero) pero esta al final de la estructura del codigo, Esa variable la necesito  poner en otro `if` al principio de la estructura del codigo y me siga dando el mismo numero que salio con el `if` de abajo.

Comment: @RicharlyxD. Lo mejor es que produzca un ejemplo mínimo, completo y autocontenido del problema, que demuestre lo que buscas.

Comment: Ya edite el ejemplo. Por favor revise mi pregunta de nuevo.

Comment: No sé que objetivo tiene responder la pregunta cuando no se entiende el problema.

Comment: @RicharlyxD. La idea es publicar un ejemplo mínimo, completo y autocontenido, que cualquiera pueda ejecutar. Yo no puedo ejecutarlo: no tengo Excel, ni Windows, ni el archivo .xlsx, ni tus directorios. Lo siento.